# ASIHTTPRequest - data from cache always empty

Tags: ios, caching, asihttprequest

I'm downloading images in my iPhone/iPad app - and because they remain the same most of the time, I'd like to cache them on disk:

```
ASIDownloadCache *cache = [ASIDownloadCache sharedCache];
[asiRequest setDownloadCache:cache];
[asiRequest setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[asiRequest setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
[asiRequest setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*30]; // Cache for 30 days
[asiRequest setDelegate:self]; // A delegate must be specified
[asiRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[asiRequest startAsynchronous];
```

In my requestFinished-method, it's recognized that the caching was successful, but the data inside my request-object is empyt; what am I missing?

```
- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   if ([request didUseCachedResponse]) {
       NSLog(@"cache, size: %i", [[request responseData] length]); // is always zero
       [self buildImageWithData:[request responseData]];
   }
   [...];
}
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:** my complete code which isn't working: the first time, I get the "not cached" statement, from then, "cache, size: 0"... I have NO idea why :(

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        asiRequest = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myimageserver.com/myimage.jpg"]];

        ASIDownloadCache *cache = [ASIDownloadCache sharedCache];
        [asiRequest setDownloadCache:cache];
        [asiRequest setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
        [asiRequest setCachePolicy:ASIOnlyLoadIfNotCachedCachePolicy];
        [asiRequest setSecondsToCache:60*60*24*30]; // Cache for 30 days
        [asiRequest setDelegate:self]; // A delegate must be specified
        [asiRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
        [asiRequest startAsynchronous];
    }
}

- (void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders {
    self.imageDataLoadedFromURL = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageDataLoadedFromURL appendData:data];
}

- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    if ([request didUseCachedResponse]) {
        NSLog(@"cache, size: %i", [[request responseData] length]); // is always zero
    } else {
        NSLog(@"not cached");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:** seems like the cache already contains the 0-byte-image; so it's not the problem of reading from caching but writing to it...

[image]

**EDIT 3:** You can download the small test project from http://tinyurl.com/68wuwj2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you set a breakpoint, clear the cache (eg. delete your app) and then step through this bit of code (ASIDownloadCache.m, line 184, method storeResponseForRequest):

```
if ([request responseData]) {
    [[request responseData] writeToFile:dataPath atomically:NO];
} else if ([request downloadDestinationPath] && ![[request downloadDestinationPath] isEqualToString:dataPath]) {
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease] copyItemAtPath:[request downloadDestinationPath] toPath:dataPath error:&error];
}
```

Check which path is followed, and check the size of request.responseData.

** **EDIT** **

Your problem is your use of didReceiveData:

```
- (void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [imageDataLoadedFromURL appendData:data];
}
```

To quote the asi http request documentation:

> If you need to process the response as
>   it comes in (for example, you want to
>   use a streaming parser to parse the
>   response while it is still being
>   downloaded), have your delegate
>   implement request:didReceiveData: (see
>   ASIHTTPRequestDelegate.h). **Note that
>   when you do this, ASIHTTPRequest will
>   not populate responseData or write the
>   response to downloadDestinationPath -
>   you must store the response yourself
>   if you need to.**

The last sentence seems to also apply to caching data.

It's probably a bug in asihttprequest, really it should either not write the data to the cache in this case or should make sure it's writing valid data - currently it looks like it writes an invalid cache entry. Do you need to process the data as it arrives? If not just remove 'didReceiveBytes' and only use the data provided in request.responseData in requestFinished.

Comment: @"Size of received data: %d bytes", [[request responseData] length] => gives 0 bytes; it takes the first path, so it writes 0 to the file...

Comment: Does your app work if you completely disable caching (ie. stopping it reading or writing to the cache, so it will always fetch from the server)? It seems like your problem may not a cache problem but a problem with the data the server is returning.

Comment: Thanks for the test app, that made it much easier - I've updated my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems correct to me.

The only thing I can think of is that you may have some "corrupt" data in your cache, like in case a zero-legth data was stored. You could try and delete the cache just once or use the `ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy` policy just once (so to "clear" the cache).

If this does not help, I would put a break point in your `requestFinished:` and from there check exactly what happened in ASIHTTP when the data was allegedly retrieved from the cache. This is easier than it sounds.

Comment: that's my point; in the requestFinished:-method, the data is already empty. ASIDoNotReadFromCacheCachePolicy didn't work unfortunately... I really have no idea what's going wrong here...

Answer (score 1):

Comment out this method:

```
(void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
   [imageDataLoadedFromURL appendData:data];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this and tell me what you get:

```
- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
    NSLog(@"Size of received data: %d bytes",[[request responseData] length]); //THIS LINE

if ([request didUseCachedResponse]) {
    NSLog(@"cached");        
} else {
        NSLog(@"not cached");
    }
}
```

Then try changing this method to:

```
- (void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveResponseHeaders:(NSDictionary *)responseHeaders {
    [self.imageDataLoadedFromURL setLength:0];
}
```

And make sure you are using `self.imageDataLoadedFromURL` as `NSMutableData`

Comment: %lu wasn't possible (compiler error); I was only able to use "%u", that resulted in 0 as well. The change of didReceiveResponseHeaders didn't have any consequences; imageDataLoadedFromURL is NSMutableData...

Comment: didn't change anything; also see my updated original post; it seems like writing to the cache doesn't work...

Comment: Oh `Size of received data: %d bytes` displays always 0 ? You havent used the updated code or your real image is 0 bytes

Comment: my real image is 0, as I found it in the cache (see my original post's edit)

Comment: i meant your server image.. Does  `Size of received data: %d bytes ` displays always 0 ?

Comment: yes; it's always displaying 0; my server image isn't 0 => if I'm trying http://www.google.ch/logos/classicplus.png, it doesn't work, e.g.

Comment: So it is not a cache problem, if the first time you make the request the data is 0, the cache is not being used then you have something wrong with your request.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your app. Alexander's suggestion is right.

Comment out this method:

```
(void) request:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

On commenting out this method, the invoked requestDone method will have the entire request content and hence the size.